# How to implement Location Sensor?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am working with android studio for last few days, and I am pretty new here with this work. I am trying to implement a location sensor app. The basic idea is if my phone enters into some restricted area (would be predefined in app), some voice message will be popped up, Surely I have to keep the app running on background to test this. I headed with `FusedLocationProviderClient` and implemented a very basic getmylocation app for now, where my actual obstacle I found. The co-ordinates keep fluctuating all the time for a same place after the decimal points by some values[(xx.xfffff,yy.yfffff) where f are the fluctuating figures,and the app is supposed to work on the truth of that figures], so the sensor can never implemented if the measurement is wrong.

Anyone having idea, how to fix this or may be there are better alternatives to implement this thing? I am pretty new to this work, so I would request you to give explanation or some attachment/article links in support of your answer so that I can get things clear and straight forward.

If any details is required from my work, Please mention , so that I can update this question on next round edit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GPS location fluctuation of several meters is normal and you could have a look at [geofencing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) in order not to unnecessarily re-invent the wheel.

Comment: GPS fluctuation of more than meters also happens.  Location tracking doesn't work by giving 100% exact answers all the time.  That's just not physically possible.  You get a location and a probability range.  You can apply a variety of smoothing algorithms on top of it.

Comment: Will it be possible, if i take help from a other device, like I Place that device in restricted area, calling it a restricted device, and my phone detects the distance from that device via may be bluetooth or wi-fi communication? That will someway solve my problem.

Comment: Bluetooth LE beacons are sometimes used for indoor (and why not also outdoor) navigation and could work in this case. They are not extremely accurate either. The idea is that the beacon has a known location and the phone detects the proximity of it. It's possible estimate the distance to the beacon, but it may also fluctuate or be off for several meters. They are called either "iBeacons", "Eddystone beacons" or "AltBeacons" are are offered by several companies like Kontakt, Estimote and others.